# django if object exists redirect to absolute url

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect, exists

I want to check if the added user input exists in the database. If it does than redirect the user to the existing object absolute url, else pass and continue with saving the input. So far I managed to check the existence and get the object but the return `HttpResponseRedirect(input_get.get_absolute_url())` is not redirecting although i can print the url correctly in the terminal (`/tags/215/baseball/`). 
Instead I get:

> "Ensure this value has at most 50 characters (it has 65)."

Any suggestions? thanks

`forms.py`

```
class TagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_tag_word(self):
        tag_word = self.cleaned_data['tag_word']
        tag_filter = TagsNew.objects.filter(tag_word=tag_word)
        if tag_filter.exists():
            tag_get = TagsNew.objects.get(tag_word=tag_word)
            tag_redirect=tag_get.get_absolute_url()
            print (tag_redirect)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(tag_redirect)
        else:
            pass
        return tag_word
```

`models.py` (get_absolute_url):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tags:tagsnew_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk, 'slug':self.slug})
```

models.py:

```
class TagsNew(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True)
    tag_word = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now= False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now= True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'tags_new'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.tag_word)
        super(TagsNew, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tags:tagsnew_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk, 'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.tag_word
```

trace:

```
/tags/221/corrections/
<ul class="errorlist"><li>tag_word<ul class="errorlist"><li>Ensure this value has at most 50 characters (it has 65).</li></ul></li></ul>
[08/Apr/2015 04:47:52] "POST /tags/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16662
[08/Apr/2015 04:47:52] "GET /static/js/ajax.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1634
[08/Apr/2015 04:47:52] "GET /static/tags/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Comment: can you please show TagsNew model? It seems you have mentioned the max length as 50 in some field.

Comment: sure I just added the models

Comment: also please add the full trace. thanks

Comment: I added the trace, Ankit Popli do you see any mistakes? Maybe the request argument is missing in clean_tag_word?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning an `HttpResponseRedirect` object in `clean_tag_word()`.  That function is expecting to return a <=50 character string to go into the `tag_word` property, but instead you're getting some big redirect object (the `return HttpResponseRedirect(tag_redirect)` line).  This object is then getting `__str__` called on it when Django tries to save it to the DB, which must have some string representation that is 65 characters long.

The solution is to move the redirection logic from your form to your controller, where it belongs.  Probably in `render_to_response()` or `form_valid()` if you are using subclasses of the generic django views.

Also, never use `else: pass`.  That is pointless.